# Add camunda webapps to (micronaut) project with embedded engine

Tags: angularjs, micronaut, camunda

**The goal**
I have a micronaut project with an embedded camunda process engine (micronaut-camunda-bpm) and I am trying to integrate the camunda webapps in the same manner as the "spring-boot-starter" for camunda.
So what I am basically trying to do is to integrate the camunda webapps into my own application.

**What I have done so far**
(According to camunda best practices embedding the webapps into your own app is not easy and there is no documentation for it.. ).
So far I added the `org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp-webjar` and tried to serve the webapps by pointing the hosting of static resources to the webjar that includes all js/html/css files. I am facing the problem that the angularjs webapps require resources through relative links starting with "$APP_ROOT" which do not get resolved properly.
E.g. stylesheets should get loaded but instead of loading them from `/app/welcome/styles/styles.css` the angularjs app tries to load them from `/app/welcome/$APP_ROOT/app/welcome/styles/styles.css` which logically results in HTTP StatusCode 404. I cannot change the links in the HTML since they are included with a dependency.

**The questions**
Is there a proper way in micronaut how I can resolve the $APP_ROOT properly?
Maybe with some kind of redirect or Filters?

Is this even the right way to integrate the camunda webapps in my own app?

Any help is higly appreciated!

Comment: I do not use micronaut, but I am aware of this issue: https://github.com/NovatecConsulting/micronaut-camunda-bpm/issues/8.  so maybe it would be best to contact Tobias and see if you get achieve this together?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I am actually working with Tobias on that Ticket and was curious if someone has some extra input for me.

Comment: Kinda funny ...

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?? I'm kind of facing the same.... Thank you

Comment: Hi @gred, yes I managed to achieve my goal. You have to add some filters from camunda which are responsible to resolve the $APP_ROOT stuff ("ProcessEnginesFilter"). Have a look at https://github.com/NovatecConsulting/micronaut-camunda-bpm/blob/master/micronaut-camunda-bpm-feature/src/main/java/info/novatec/micronaut/camunda/bpm/feature/JettyServerCustomizer.java

Comment: @martisaw thank you very much for your update... I will check them out.